# Base table or view already exists! (laravel voyager)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, php-7, voyager

When I run

```
php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy
```

I get this error:

```
Base table or view already exists
C:\project\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 La table 'users' existe déjà")
```

I guess that "users" table is already reserved by laravel !

How can I solve this issue please?

Comment: delete the 'users' table from database

Answer (score 0):

**This happens because you all ready has a table with this name in your DB, Voyager will not replace for you.**

Use the command

> php artisan migrate:reset

This command will rollback all laravel database migrations for you, after that just run again

> php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy

And will works tasty.